# Different between Curl -u and basic auth

Tags: curl

I am getting the same results using `curl -X POST www.example.com -d "code : 123" -u user:pwd`

And using Postman on chrome, in the basic auth tab, putting `user:pwd`, to generate a Authorization code (which looks like some encoded string)

Is there no difference?

Comment: Duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25969196 https://stackoverflow.com/q/36292406

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default in curl (i.e. unless you add --digest, --negotiate, --ntlm or --anyauth) is to use Basic authentication, so yes, it is the same.

Note that if you have -d, you don't need the -X POST, as it is implied.