# How to define the basic HTTP authentication using cURL correctly?

Tags: http, curl, authorization, basic-authentication, laminas-api-tools

I'm learning Apigility ([Apigility docu -> REST Service Tutorial](https://www.apigility.org/documentation/intro/first-rest-service)) and trying to send a POST request with basic authentication via cURL:

```
$ curl -X POST -i -H "Content-Type: application/hal+json" -H "Authorization: Basic YXBpdXNlcjphcGlwd2Q=" http://apigilityhw.sandbox.loc/status
```

`YXBpdXNlcjphcGlwd2Q=` is the base 64 encoded string with my credentials `apiuser:apipwd`. The credentials are saved in the `/data/htpasswd` (`apiuser:$apr1$3J4cyqEw$WKga3rQMkxvnevMuBaekg/`).

The looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx/1.4.7
Date: Mon, 22 Sep 2014 07:48:47 GMT
Content-Type: application/problem+json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.12-1~dotdeb.1
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="api"
```

Where is the mistake here? How to get it work?

Answer (score 671, accepted):

```
curl -u username:password http://
curl -u username http://
```

From the documentation page:

> **-u, --user <user:password>**
>
> Specify the user name and password to use for server authentication.
> Overrides -n, --netrc and --netrc-optional.
>
> If you simply specify the user name, curl will prompt for a password.
>
> The user name and passwords are split up on the first colon, which
> makes it impossible to use a colon in the user name with this option.
> The password can, still.
>
> When using Kerberos V5 with a Windows based server you should include
> the Windows domain name in the user name, in order for the server to
> succesfully obtain a Kerberos Ticket. If you don't then the initial
> authentication handshake may fail.
>
> When using NTLM, the user name can be specified simply as the user
> name, without the domain, if there is a single domain and forest in
> your setup for example.
>
> To specify the domain name use either Down-Level Logon Name or UPN
> (User Principal Name) formats. For example, EXAMPLE\user and
> user@example.com respectively.
>
> If you use a Windows SSPI-enabled curl binary and perform Kerberos V5,
> Negotiate, NTLM or Digest authentication then you can tell curl to
> select the user name and password from your environment by specifying
> a single colon with this option: "-u :".
>
> If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-u

Note that you do not need [`--basic`](http://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--basic) flag as it is the default.

Comment: If your password contains some special characters like ? or @ then you have to put it into single ticks. 
curl -u 'username:?p@ssword' http://

Comment: but what does this actual request look like? I feel like alot of people test with curl but then write code ect in whatever language they use. does the --user info get sent as a header? If so what should that header look like

Comment: @GautamKathrotiya in Postman there is a Basic Auth option in the Authorization tab of a request, it will insert this Authorization header for you.

Comment: @Verty00 you can use the -v flag with curl to see the contents of the request.

Comment: Put a colon after username if your password is empty to avoid a password prompt.

Answer (score 71):

as header

```
AUTH=$(echo -ne "$BASIC_AUTH_USER:$BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD" | base64 --wrap 0)

curl \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --header "Authorization: Basic $AUTH" \
  --request POST \
  --data  '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}' \
  https://example.com/
```

Comment: Could you add the header option for Windows 10?

Comment: @DrDave what do you mean?

Comment: I've gotten a little past this, but I am having an issue where when I send a base64 encoded username:password string to authenticate a substring error is raised.  I asked about Windows 10 because there is some "conversion" needed when using *NIX curl statements under Windows 10, in part because there are at least 3 different utilities that give curl-like functionality in Windows- including curl embedded in Git, curl within Windows 10 and the " expert recommended" approaches using command-lets for making command line URL calls in WIndows 10

Comment: @DrDave I will add the variant of invoking curl that  works on windows, if someone will send it to me)

Answer (score 18):

The easiest way to figure out what authorization header should look like might be first to run **curl** with **-u** (or putting the credentials within the URL) and **-v** and the output will show the request header:

```sh
$ curl -v -u 'apiuser:apipwd' ... http://apigilityhw.sandbox.loc/status

# OR putting the credentials in the URL: 

$ curl -v ... http://apiuser:apipwd@apigilityhw.sandbox.loc/status
    
# copy and paste the "Authorization" header from the output:
    
$ curl -H 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YXBpcHdk' ... http://apigilityhw.sandbox.loc/status
```