# API rate limit exceeded message is still appear after the authentication have been done

Tags: git, github

I getting this message

```
 API rate limit exceeded for ######. (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit.
```

because I exceed the rate limit. I had been able to request for 5000 requests with not problem. suddenly today I am not able to do so. the limit is 60. I use the basic authentication to get the 5000 requests again, but it still same 60.

https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication

I am trying to fetch issues for github I am using this command

```
 wget -O issues.txt --no-check-certificate --quiet "https://api.github.com/repos/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues?state=all&labels=Bug&per_page=100&page=1"
```

I am using wget to download the issues from github. Is there a way to set the authentication to work for wget with github ( same way that curl work)?

Comment: I don't see the basic authentication string inside your last command, remember that because basic is a really old protocol, it needs to be repeated every request

Comment: Is there a way  to set the authentication for request?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define the basic HTTP authentication using cURL correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969196/how-to-define-the-basic-http-authentication-using-curl-correctly)

Comment: I have tried this option but it is not working. Also I am using wget.