# Api request to the BitBucket is failing

Tags: python, api, bitbucket

I wanted to get a list of repositories in a workspace of BitBucket and found out such a command.

```
curl --request GET   --url 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}'   --header 'Authorization: Bearer {token}'   --header 'Accept: application/json'
```

I use a free plan of BitBucket and use for "Authorization" Basic  [authentication](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/intro/#basic-auth)
Because I had problems with oauth2. And now I use th

```
curl --request GET   --url 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}'   --header 'Authorization: Basic {app password}'   --header 'Accept: application/json'
```

But still getting such an error:
`Uauthorized` or `Token is invalid or not supported for this endpoint`
Has anyone faced such an issue or do you know any way how to perform that using any other ways (python ) ?

Comment: Are you just malformatting your basic auth payload? For example not base64 encoding the {username}:{password}? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969196/how-to-define-the-basic-http-authentication-using-curl-correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your auth header is properly constructed. From [bitbucket docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/example-basic-authentication/#supplying-basic-auth-headers):

> #### Supplying Basic Auth headers
>
> 1. Build a string of the form username:password BASE64 encode the string
> 2. Supply an "Authorization" header with content "Basic " followed by the
> 3. encoded string, e.g. Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=

`curl` also comes built-in with helpers to do this for you with `-u` switch also in the docs page linked above:

> `curl -D- -u fred:fred -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:7990/rest/api/1.0/projects`

### With python

Alternatively if you want to do this with python, you can do something like this with the `requests` library([docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/authentication/#basic-authentication)) or something similar with another library like `httpx` ([docs](https://www.python-httpx.org/quickstart/#authentication)):

```py
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
basic = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass')
requests.get('https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/pass', auth=basic)
# <Response [200]>
```

> In fact, HTTP Basic Auth is so common that Requests provides a handy shorthand for using it:

```py
requests.get('https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/pass', auth=('user', 'pass'))
# <Response [200]>
```