# How do I log into a site with curl or javascript?

Tags: javascript, session, curl, cookies, header

I'm studying the basics of XSRF on Portswigger and I've completed [Lab: CSRF vulnerability with no defenses](https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf/lab-no-defenses) with FireFox. I attempted to go a step further by completing the same lab from the terminal. However when I send a request to the server, it returns the body for the login page; so authentication is not working, even though I've provided the username and password to access the account in the lab.

I aim to test logging in with `curl` and then automate with `javascript`.

Here is Zshell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

curl -iLs --compressed \
--user 'wiener':'peter' --cookie-jar ./tmpCookie.txt \
"https://0ad500d004b92108827b3d3c00770085.web-security-academy.net/login"

curl -iLs --compressed \
--cookie ./tmpCookie.txt \
"https://0ad500d004b92108827b3d3c00770085.web-security-academy.net/my-account?id=wiener"
```

Here is JavaScript:

```
//!/usr/bin/env node

const req = require("axios"); // http requests

// Function to authenticate and obtain session token
async function authenticate(url, username, password) {
    try {
        const response = await req.post(url, { username, password });
        return response.headers["session-token"]; // Assuming server returns session token in headers
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
        return null;
    }
}

// Make authenticated requests.
async function main() {
    const urL = "https://0ad500d004b92108827b3d3c00770085.web-security-academy.net/login"
    const sessionToken = await authenticate(urL, "wiener", "peter");
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript is sending the credentials as part of the POST body:

```
await req.post(url, { username, password })
```

The cURL command is sending it as [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27442239/328193):

```
--user 'wiener':'peter'
```

These are two very different things.  You can match the JavaScript version by adding a JSON body to the cURL request (and making it a POST request):

```
curl -iLs --compressed \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '{"username":"wiener","password":"peter"}' \
  --cookie-jar ./tmpCookie.txt \
  "https://0ad500d004b92108827b3d3c00770085.web-security-academy.net/login"
```

Comment: For some odd reason the server does not accept `--header "Content-Type: application/json"`. I modified your curl solution by removing the content type header and changing data to `--data 'username=wiener&password=peter'`. This worked. Now the next step is to implement this in JavaScript.

Comment: @MichaelŠòdéké: Do you mean that the JavaScript code you posted *also* wasn't working?  I'd thought that was the working request you were trying to replicate in cURL.  If the server *isn't* expecting a JSON body and is expecting form data then you can [post form data with Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47630163/328193) as well.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it later. I have other work to take care of. If it doesn't work, I'll notify you.