# How to request access token for Reddit on Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, reddit, reddit-access-token

I have been trying to figure out how to acquire an access token from [Reddit API](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2-Quick-Start-Example) in Google Apps Script. I have below code written so far:

```
function main() {
  
  var username = 'myredditusername';
  var pwd = 'myredditpassword';
  var client_id = 'myredditclientid';
  var client_secret = 'myredditclientsecret';

  var access_token_url = 'https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token';
  var api_url = 'https://oauth.reddit.com/';
  var user_agent = 'MySideProjectUserAgent';

var data = {
  'grant_type': 'password',
  'username': username,
  'password': pwd
};

var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(data),
  'headers': {'User-Agent': user_agent},
  // what do I enter here to pass my client_id and client_secret?    
};

var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(access_token_url, options);
console.log(resp.getContentText());
}
```

Running the above code receives an error like below (not surprising because I still need to figure out how to pass in my `client_id` and `client_secret`):

```
Exception: Request failed for https://www.reddit.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: {"message": "Unauthorized", "error": 401} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
```

When using `curl`, I was able to acquire the token successfully with this command:

```
curl -X POST -A 'KeywordTrackAgent' -d "grant_type=password&username=myredditusername&password=myredditpassword" --user 'client_id:client_secret' https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token
```

From reaching around ([example post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62968667/1330974)), I figured that if I were to translate this `curl` request to a `POST` request, I'd need to add `Authorization` field to my `headers` parameter with the format like below:

```
function main() {
  
  var username = 'myredditusername';
  var pwd = 'myredditpassword';
  var client_id = 'myredditclientid';
  var client_secret = 'myredditclientsecret';

  var access_token_url = 'https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token';
  var api_url = 'https://oauth.reddit.com/';
  var user_agent = 'MySideProjectUserAgent';

var data = {
  'grant_type': 'password',
  'username': username,
  'password': pwd
};

var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(data),
  'headers': {
    'User-Agent': user_agent,
    // Below, I decided to encode my client_id and client_secret in base64 with the prefix 'Basic '
    'Authorization': 'Basic clientIdAndClientSecretInBase64',
    },
};

var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(access_token_url, options);
console.log(JSON.parse(resp.getContentText()));
}
```

I'm still receiving { error: 'unsupported_grant_type' }.

Could anyone--who has successfully fetched Reddit access token using JavaScript and preferably, using Google Apps Script--share some suggestion/insight on this? Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to convert the following curl command to Google Apps Script.

  ```
    curl -X POST -A 'KeywordTrackAgent' -d "grant_type=password&username=myredditusername&password=myredditpassword" --user 'client_id:client_secret' https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token
  ```

This curl command sends the data as the form data. And, the basic authorization is used. When these are reflected to the Google Apps Script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

In this script, your values are used.

```
function main() {
  var username = 'myredditusername';
  var pwd = 'myredditpassword';
  var client_id = 'myredditclientid';
  var client_secret = 'myredditclientsecret';
  var access_token_url = 'https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token';

  var data = {
    'grant_type': 'password',
    'username': username,
    'password': pwd
  };
  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': data,
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(`${client_id}:${client_secret}`),
    },
  };
  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(access_token_url, options);
  console.log(JSON.parse(resp.getContentText()));
}
```

- At this script, the request is same with the curl command.

#### Note:

- In this script, it supposes that the values for authorizating are correct. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: thank you very much! Your suggestion works. :) I shouldn't have included `'contentType' : 'application/json'` and `stringify()` the `'payload'`. That was the difference that made it all work. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1330974 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.