# Curl to rest assured API

Tags: java, rest

Am trying to use REST-Assured from GET curl request:

```
curl --location --request GET \
"https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/<REPO-KEY>/<GROUPD-ID>/<ARTIFACT-ID>/<VERSION>-SNAPSHOT/file1.xml" \
--header 'originating_ip: 127.0.0.1' \
--user 'username:password' \
--output jrog_test_output
```

Here is the REST-Assured request:

```
given().header("originating_ip", "127.0.0.1").formParam("username","username").formParam("password","password").log().all().get(url).then().log().all().assertThat().statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
```

This does not connect and don't get logs. How should the username and password get assigned.

Comment: This should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292406/what-does-user-mean-with-curl

It gets converted into an Authorization Header that contains base64 encoding of the username:password.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Authorisation header works with Base64 encode like:
echo -n "username:password" | base64 => outputs encoded value
.header("Authorization", "Basic ")